# What is the use case of SUM vs SUMX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm learning DAX.

For a measure, I can write: `Profit = SUM(Sales[SalesAmt])-SUM(Sales[ProdcutionCost])`

This gives me the Profit.

I get the same result if I do: `Profit = SUMX(Sales,Sales[SalesAmt]-Sales[ProdcutionCost])`

So what is the use case or difference between SUM and SUMX?

Comment: [SUM vs. SUMX](https://www.google.com/search?q=dax+sum+vs+sumx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, `SUM` is just syntactic sugar for simple sums of a column.

```
SUM ( 'Table'[Column] )
```

is shorthand for (and will be translated to by the engine at query time)

```
SUMX ( 'Table' , 'Table'[Column] )
```

and the use case is, again, for when you only want a simple sum. If you want to do more things *in a row context* across your table, you need to invoke `SUMX`.

Consider a case where you have a table like this, with unit price and quantity and want to calculate the total revenue:

| Transaction ID | Product ID | Unit Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5.99 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 10.49 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 5.99 | 3 |

In this case you cannot do:

```
Total Revenue = SUM ( 'Table'[Unit Price] ) * SUM ( 'Table'[Quantity] )
```

Instead you would have to use the row context in the explicit `SUMX` iterator to sum row by row:

```
Total Revenue = 
    SUMX ( 
        'Table' , 
        'Table'[Unit Price] * 'Table'[Quantity]
    )
```

Comment: So this is relevant only for calculated column, and not for measures?

Comment: I would say in my example it's the complete opposite. In a calculated column in the example table, calculating `Revenue` would just be `Revenue = [Unit Price] * [Quantity]`. In a way, the way the measure is written, it is analogous to (but not the same as..) adding a temporary calculated column based on the table, and sum over it directly.